# Url Protocol is not assigned when publishing through store

Tags: wpf, windows-app-sdk, microsoft-store

I developed one application and planned to publish in store , I have google sign in in my application so when ever  click the sign in open the browser and select the required mail id and relaunch the application  , for he relaunching the application use the Costume URL Protocol scheme by registering the application exe path. This is working fine while running in visual studio . But when i am publishing my appxbundle in store app opening successfully but when i am going through google sign in app does not relaunching , Custome url protocol is not created in registery editor

```
string applicationLocation = typeof(App).Assembly.Location;
var rootFolders = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", true).OpenSubKey("Classes", true);
var createSubKey = rootFolders.CreateSubKey("appname");
createSubKey.SetValue("URL Protocol", " ");
createSubKey.CreateSubKey(@"shell\open\command").SetValue("", $"\"{applicationLocation}\" \"%1\" \"%2\"");
```

kindly suggest me any solution on this , Thanks in Advance